# Repeating a List in Scala

Tags: scala

I am a Scala noob. I have decided to write a spider solitaire solver as a first exercise to learn the language and functional programming in general.

I would like to generate a randomly shuffled deck of cards containing 1, 2, or 4 suits. Here is what I came up with:

```
val numberOfSuits = 1
(List("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades").take(numberOfSuits) * 4).take(4)
```

which should return

```
List("clubs", "clubs", "clubs", "clubs")
List("clubs", "diamonds", "clubs", "diamonds")
List("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades")
```

depending on the value of numberOfSuits, except there is no List "multiply" operation that I can find. Did I miss it? Is there a better way to generate the complete deck before shuffling?

BTW, I plan on using an Enumeration for the suits, but it was easier to type my question with strings. I will take the List generated above and using a for comprehension, iterate over the suits and a similar List of card "ranks" to generate a complete deck.

Comment: The interesting part of this project will be creating the immutable generations of the tableau (current layout of the cards). I ask the current tableau for a list of legal moves, returned as tuples of (source column, destination column, and source position). I then apply each to the current tableau in a recursive fashion using some kind of mini-max algorithm to find the "best" move. I also want the card object to be immutable, so the tableaus ("tableaux?") will have to know if a card is face up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look up the scaladoc for the object `List`. It has all manners of interesting methods for creation of lists. For instance, the following does exactly what you were trying to:

```
List.flatten(List.make(4, List("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades").take(numberOfSuits))).take(4)
```

A much nicer code, however, would be this (Scala 2.7):

```
val suits = List("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades")
List.tabulate(4, i => suits.apply(i % numberOfSuits))
```

On Scala 2.8 `tabulate` is curried, so the correct syntax would be:

```
List.tabulate(4)(i => suits.apply(i % numberOfSuits))
```

Comment: I tried your example, but get an error on 2.8.0.Beta1-prerelease.  In fact, I get this error on most samples of List.tabulate I can find.  What gives?

scala> List.tabulate(4, i => suits.apply(i % numberOfSuits))      
<console>:5: error: missing parameter type
       List.tabulate(4, i => suits.apply(i % numberOfSuits))

scala> List.tabulate(4, (i:Int) => suits.apply(i % numberOfSuits))
<console>:7: error: overloaded method value tabulate with alternatives....cannot be applied to (Int,(Int) => java.lang.String)
       List.tabulate(4, (i:Int) => suits.apply(i % numberOfSuits))
            ^

Comment: @Adam The syntax changed slightly from 2.7 to 2.8. See the edited answer.

Comment: Funny you should mention it. I forgot that the singleton docs were at the bottom of the package doc pages. In the comment I wrote above, I came up with the *EXACT* same answer you offered first above.

Comment: This code here

    `List.tabulate(4, i => suits.apply(i % numberOfSuits))`

does not require `apply` call. I would change this to

    `List.tabulate(4, i => suits(i % numberOfSuits))`

Answer (score 19):

Flatten a finite lists of lists:

```
scala> List.fill(2)(List(1, 2, 3, 4)).flatten
res18: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Flatten an infinite Stream of lists, take the first N elements:

```
scala> Stream.continually(List(1, 2, 3, 4)).flatten.take(8).toList
res19: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Is this a new method in 2.8.0? I could not get it to work, but this did: val suits = List("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"); List.flatten(List.make(4, suits.take(1))), where the "1" is the numberOfSuits value.

Comment: Yes, some of these are new in 2.8.

Answer (score 6):

You can expand a numeric sequence and `flatMap` instead of multiplying.

```
scala> (1 to 3).flatMap(_=>List(1,2,3,4).take(2)).take(4)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 1, 2)
```

This works in 2.7.x also.

---

Edit: since you're less experienced with Scala, you may not yet have come across the enrich-my-library pattern.  If you want to multiply your lists a lot, you can add a custom conversion class:

```
class MultipliableList[T](l: List[T]) {
  def *(n: Int) = (1 to n).flatMap(_=>l).toList
}
implicit def list2multipliable[T](l: List[T]) = new MultipliableList[T](l)
```

and now you can

```
scala> List(1,2,3)*4
res2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3)
```

(Generally, to reuse such implicits, declare them in an object and then import MyObject._ to get the implicit conversion and corresponding class in scope.)

Comment: In Scala 2.13.4, `scala> List(1,2,3)*4` raise an error: `error: value * is not a member of List[Int]`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `cats` library, you can make use of `Semigroup`'s method `combineN`. It repeates a list `N` times.

```
import cats.implicits._
import cats.syntax.semigroup._

scala> List("clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades").combineN(2)
res1: List[String] = List(clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades, clubs, diamonds, hearts, spades)
```

Comment: @Saibō what `cats` version do you use?